# Ubuntu 15.04 Login fails and returns to login

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, login, 15.04

I recently upgraded my desktop from an NVIDIA 560ti graphics card to a 970 SC. Before upgrading the card, I updated to Vivid Vervet with no issues. After upgrading the card, my login screen is blown up (maybe 720p) as opposed to 1080p on the old card, and login attempts result in some text flashing by and a return to the login.

I also tried booting into the LiveUSB version of 14.10, but this failed too.

I'm certain the problem lies in the new graphics card. Several other threads suggest installing new or experimental drivers, but I can't even access the terminal. Is there any official support for the new card, or am I out of luck for now?

Comment: If it were me, id power it back on and grab the IP address from the router and get putty and ssh into the machine. Then get drivers and install and see how it works. Or the other option is to remove the card and go with the onboard (if there is one) get the drivers uninstalled and reinstall new drivers and then put the new card in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a lot of questions on askubuntu about constantly returning to the login screen.

I've upgraded machines with AMD and nVidia cards from 14.04 to 15.04 (through 14.10) and on both I had this issue. (proprietary drivers)

Both resolved.

### For nVidia

When in login screen, launched the terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

found the drivers:

```
dpkg -l | grep nvidia
```

reinstalled them with `apt-get remove <package name>` and `apt-get install <package name>`

### For AMD

In login screen launched the terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

found the drivers:

```
dpkg -l | grep amd
```

and just removed them with `apt-get remove <package name>`

MESA opensource drivers were installed, so it worked.

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll have to ssh in and install those drivers. Glad to hear official drivers are available.

Comment: I was able to uninstall the drivers, but I'm not able to reinstall them. I found this forum post (http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04/) that points towards the xorg-edgers ppa as the location of the newest drivers. I attempted to install nvidia-343 but my problem persists. I found NVIDIA's official driver download for 343 here (http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/80145) but I don't know how to get that onto my linux machine using the terminal.